# How to estimate a stochastic time delay

Tags: time-series, estimation, stochastic-processes

Say I have irregular samples of two random processes that are both based on an unobserved process, $Z(t)$.  Their SDEs are

$\mathrm{d}X(t) = \mathrm{d}Z(t-u(t)) + \epsilon(t)$

$\mathrm{d}Y(t) = \mathrm{d}Z(t-v(t)) + \eta(t)$

where $\epsilon(t)$ and $\eta(t)$ are white noise and $Z(t)$ is any Levy process.  The delays, $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ are independent, continuous, and $\ge0$.

I am interested in the relative delay, $u(t) - v(t)$, between the two observed processes.  Any suggestions on how to estimate its expectation? What about its 2nd moment?

Comment: $dX(t)-dY(t) = dZ(t+u(t)) - dZ(t+v(t)) + \epsilon(t) - \eta(t) = dZ(u(t) - v(t)) + \epsilon(t) + \eta(t)$, the variance seems $\sigma^2 (\epsilon(t)) + \sigma^2(\eta(t))$

Comment: I don't quite follow that. I'm looking for an estimator of the moments based on actual observations of the two processes.